# 404 on accessing file outside public directory

Tags: php, apache

I'm fairly new to php and I'm trying to build a to-do application.

I have a basic html form inside a folder called **public** like so:

```html
    <form method="POST" action="src/create.php">
            <label>Task:</label>
            <input name="title" type="text"  placeholder="Name your task..." required>
            <br>
            <label>Task description: </label>
            <input name="description" type="text" placeholder="Description" required>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create a task">
        </form>
```

..And like the action suggests I have a folder **src** where I'm trying to insert data into database like so:

```php
    <?php
    include_once __DIR__ . '/../database/conn_db.php';

    if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
        
        $taskTitle = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST["title"]);
        $taskDescription = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST["description"]);

        if(empty($_POST["title"])) {
            header("Location: ../public/index.php?create=error".urlencode("Invalid title"));
            exit();
        }
        if(empty($_POST["description"])) {
            header("Location: ../public/index.php?create=error".urlencode("Invalid description"));
            exit();
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO todolist.tasks (title, description) VALUES ('$taskTitle', '$taskDescription')";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        header("Location: ../public/index.php?create=success");
    }
```

When I submit data into **create.php** I bump into a *404 The requested URL was not found on this server* error

I've already tried `action="../src/create.php` and so on, but for some reason, I just can't access the src folder or the files within it.

My folder structure is as follows:

public
--index.php
src
--create.php
database
--conn_db.php

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

P.S. When I'm using Xdebug's live server everything works well, but when I'm using Apache 2.4 (WIN) this error happens.

Comment: From your file structure I would *assume* that your webserver (apache) is set up to only allow public access to your `public` directory.   
This means that you need to put all pages that a user might need to access by URL in `/public`

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'd like to secure that no one will be able to finger my files outside the **public** folder. Thing is, that I still need access to my **src** folder (and the files within it) in order to be able to create new tasks and use the functions that I'm about to create. Do you have any suggestions how I should do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can move your `/src` to be inside `/public` or you can use [`include`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) to use files from `/src` in a file that is in `/public`.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are trying on your development pc.  In which case you need to use something like this

`action="localhost/src/create.php"`

Otherwise, the browser does not know what domain you are looking at.  Of course, for deployment, you have to change the path.

Here are some ways to achieve this

1. I have a function that I have called **make_link** that uses a Debug flag to return a different prefix for the path.
2. Have a prefix that you set in a **common.php** based on whether you are debugging or running on the production server.  Include this in all your pages and prefix all your public paths (not include paths).
3. Have the prefix variable in php.ini
4. More secure method is to have an environment variable in the **.htaccess** file